# Is it safe to use a phone while charging it with a powerbank?

Tags: charging

Is it safe to use a phone while charging it using a power bank or is it as dangerous while using it with a charging cable?

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly safe to use the phone while it is being charged.  If the battery is very depleted, the phone may get a bit warm to hot.  This is normal, but do not cover it with any material.

It is definitely not a good idea to put in under the pillow while it is charging.